# Reuse of arm shared library

Tags: android, c++, shared-libraries

I have got built already arm android shared library (libtest.so). I am interested in reusing one function (that hasn't many dependencies - it just creates class instance and invokes two methods). I would like to invoke that function (it takes one std::string argument) and get returned value.

Is it possible to do such thing? I don't have any header files.

I've tried this Android.mk, I put libtest.so in `/jni` and `/libs/armeabi`, `/lib/armeabi`. At this point my `cpp` file compiles, but now what? If it is possible, how can I invoke function from libtest.so? I know its name from objdump

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE:= libtest
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtest.so
 include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.cpp
 LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtest
 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Edit:**

I've tried to add prebuild library from hello-jni sample with this android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libhello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libhello-jni.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And it worked, but the same code for `libtest.so` shows following error (while starting)

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load libtest.so: FindLibrary returned null
```

libtest.so is present in folder (on the device at `/data/data/[package]/lib`) next to libhello-jni.so. What may be wrong?

Comment: If the library is built for the correct ABI, putting it in the appropriate lib directory should get it included in the apk and unpacked on a compatible device.  At that point you should be able to load it from Java *before* you load the JNI-interfaced library which depends on it, or invoke the dynamic loader from the C side. There may also be some ways to get this to happen automatically, but doing it explicitly shouldn't be hard.  I'd be more worried about getting the compiler side of things correct - you might try creating a fake version to build against.

Comment: Thanks for the description Chris, could you please check updated question?

Comment: You could have lost the execute bit, or the file could not in fact be compatible with the ABI?  Try playing with the NDK's readelf or objdump to compare that library to your built-from-source one.  You could also try as a test giving the explicit full pathname of the .so file as installed on the device to System.load() instead of loadLibrary() - likely it will fail to load the file, but you might learn something from the errors generated.

Comment: for the unsatisfied link error, if you have build the libtest.so with shared runtime your libtest.so most probably depends on libgnu_shared.so So you should Load it first and then try to load libtest.so

Comment: I managed to load `libtest.so` using `loadLibrary()` with full direct path instead of `System.load()`. But... how can I call `std::string md5(std::string)` function from `libtest.so`? I tried to write header file with that function declaration but compiler shows function is not defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an application where I do something similar to what you need (or maybe exactly what you need).

1. I have pre-compiled libraries in the form of *.so files. (e.g. lib1.so, lib2.so etc.),
   which come with some headers.
2. I have created a module which is making use of the pre-compiled libraries by including their headers and the *.so files. In the example I've called it 'libtestwrapper'. The module defines its own source files and optionally includes. The module functionality can be exported for a second module (if you provide header files) as explained later.
3. I have created a second module (newModule) which is making use of the first one (libtestwrapper) by adding it to the 'LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES'. This makes your previously exported header files (in 'libtestwrapper') available to 'newModule'.

Here is the content of my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtestwrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtestUsage.c # Use the methods of libtest.h here
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include # This is where libtest.h should be

# provide this line if you intend to export any header files to another module
#LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include # you may also use a different directory than 'include'

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/dir_with_libtest_so -libtest # -llog etc.
                                #optionally add any as needed: -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -ldl -lgcc
                                # '-libtest' corresponds to 'libtest.so' - the names must match
                                # -llog is for logcat for example
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Optional:
# Define a second module wich is making use of the first one (i.e. libtestwrapper)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := newModule # this module will be making use of the first one (if needed)
                    # Add local source files. If the files are stored in directories
                    # you have to provide a relative path  starting inside the 'jni' directory.
                    # The example is for this structure: jni/dirToSourceFiles1/*.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := dirToSourceFiles1/SourceFile1.cpp dirToSourceFiles1/SourceFile2.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/newModule_include # path where the headers of this module are stored
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libtestwrapper # make use of the previous module

# Optionally add this line if any other libs should be used
#LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -ldl -lgcc
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the library was not built with the Android build tools (i.e. NDK) then it likely won't have a compatible ABI. Even if it was built using an ARMv5 EABI compatible version of gcc, if it depends on any libc/libc++ then it will fail.  The bionic C library is not binary compatible with other C/C++ libraries and you must build native code against it, even for a shared library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a C++ method from Java and need to pass types like string you should write a conversion layer using JNI (Java Native interface).

You may find several tutorials on how this is done in the internet. An example 
[here](http://thebreakfastpost.com/2012/01/21/wrapping-a-c-library-with-jni-introduction/)

As a summary

1- Declare a native method in Java

2- Generate the signature that should be exported from your c++ library which will be called when this method is called in Java.

Sample command : javah com.companyname.JavaTestCaller

This command willgenerate a header file with the appropriate signature.

3- Prepare a c++ library that contains this method. Do whatever you want in this method(make calls into libtest.so if you want ) and return the result. Use methods from  when type conversions are necessary.

4- Put this new library next to your libtest.so in your application. Load this library after libtest.so.

5- Call the native Java method from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this line:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtest
```

to:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := test
```

lib and .so are automatically used to resolve the shared library name. You should also be able to use:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ltest
```

PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY is another option.

Since you don't have a header file, you may need to write a shared library that you use to call the prebuilt library.  Your app will call the new shared library which exports the properly names JNI symbols and the new shared library will call the md5() function.